# Usage of experimental feature of CSS --> element.pseudo();

Tags: css, pseudo-element, browser-feature-detection

Has anyone tried to use a new feature of CSS, in others words this feature

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSPseudoElement

const element = document.querySelector('q');

const cssPseudoElement = element.pseudo('::before');

I always receive that info in console --> Uncaught TypeError: element.pseudo is not a function ...

I have tried to recreate this on Firefox developer version, but did not receive the same result. I have turned a needed flag about:confing --> dom.css_pseudo_element.enabled.

To be cleared the example that is shown in above documentation.

Regards,

Comment: What's your question? This is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: It is simple, how to use this feature ?

Comment: *Uncaught TypeError: element.pseudo is not a function .* --> logical since it's an experimental feature (read until the end of the link to see the support)

Comment: According to documentation, you can turn this feature on, setting flags in firefox as I wrote, so it should working

Comment: Your link explains that this only works for FF. Why would you even be considering this unless you're writing something that is FF specific? Voting to close since it's unclear what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing (September 2020), `pseudo()` is still very much a work in progress. You should not expect it to work at this early stage.

See:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#dom-element-pseudo

and:

- https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3607
- https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3603

---

Instead, the **standard approach** for accessing a pseudo element like `::before` or `::after` is:

```
var pseudoElementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(myElement, '::before');
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle